# Drawing underline for UIButton is hidden behind views

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewcontroller with 3 `UIButtons` that have the same Y position but 20px apart from each other horizontally.  When a button is selected, I'd like to draw a line beneath the button.  I tried just adding the underline attribute, but the line isn't really customizable.  I have the buttons on top of a UIImageView that is contained within a subclass of UIView I named SectionView.

In my view controller i have the following function that is called when a button is pressed:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sectionView: SectionView!

func sectionButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.sectionView.selectedButton = sender
    self.sectionView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

In my UIView subclass, I have the following:

```
class SectionView: UIView {

    var selectedButton: UIButton?

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let linePath = UIBezierPath()

        linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:(self.selectedButton?.frame.origin.x)! - 3, y: (self.selectedButton?.frame.origin.y)! + 35))
        linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: (self.selectedButton?.frame.origin.x)! + (self.selectedButton?.frame.width)! + 3, y: (self.selectedButton?.frame.origin.y)! + 35))
        linePath.closePath()
        UIColor.purpleColor().set()
        linePath.stroke()
        linePath.fill()
    }
}
```

I can get the line to draw at the position and length I desire, but its beneath the UIButton and UIImageView.  How can I get it to appear above?

Answer (score 1):

```
func addLine(button:UIButton)// pass button object as a argument
{
    let length = button.bounds.width
    let x  =  button.bounds.origin.x
    let y = button.bounds.origin.y + button.bounds.height - 5
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + length , y:y))
    //design path in layer
    let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    lineLayer.path = path.cgPath
    lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    lineLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    lineLayer.fillColor  = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    button.layer.insertSublayer(lineLayer, at: 0)
}`
```

// This code will create one line below your button(using UIBezierPath and Layers )

Answer (score 0):

I had to change it up.  Instead of using a bezier path, I ended up creating a `UIView` and placing it above the other views.

```
func sectionButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let lineView = createView(sender)
    self.sectionView.addSubview(lineView)
}

func createView(sender:UIButton) -> UIView {

    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x, y: sender.frame.origin.y + 12, width: sender.frame.width, height: 2.0))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    return customView

}
```

Remember, my buttons are on top of a `UIImageView` that is contained within a `UIView`.  When I tried to add the line view as a subview to the imageview, the line wouldn't line up with the x origin of the button. So instead I added the line view as a subview to the `UIView` and it came out looking correct.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `CALayer` to draw lines. Add the following code in your button action, this may help.

```
@IBAction func sectionButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: sender.frame.size.height - 2,
                           width:  sender.frame.size.width, height: 2)
    border.borderWidth = 2.0
    sender.layer.addSublayer(border)
    sender.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: What are the benefits to using a `CALayer` vs a `UIView`

Comment: Just an alternate to UIView and seems to be a straightforward way